# Spark UI of certain application_id is slow when job is running for quite some time

Tags: apache-spark

When I click the application_id of a long running job (say 24 hours) in Spark UI, it is taking a long time to load the stages. I don't know if it's connected with my spark config or my deploy-mode client. Here's more info of my spark config:

```
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--driver-memory 12g \
--executor-memory 8g \
--executor-cores 4 \
--num-executors 108 \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI is running on the machine of the driver. Therefore, if the machine runs out of RAM, the UI gets very slow.

Here I see that you request 12GB of RAM for the driver. This is a lot and if this is all the memory available on the machine, it makes sense that the UI gets very slow at some point. This process is only supposed to **drive** the computation and share it between the workers.

I guess that you are collecting a large amount of data which is generally not a good idea. (see https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/dont_call_collect_on_a_very_large_rdd.html)

A better option would be to write the RDD to a file or a distributed DB.

Comment: Your answer is perfect. I did not had the thought that the UI is running on the machine of the driver. Thank you very much for your answer.